# What is the difference between 'Corporate' and 'Corporation'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've done an extensive search but didn't find anything on that.

Is 'Corporate' (as a noun) simply a shorter form of 'Corporation'?

Also, if a condition dictates that 'a company name can't include the word corporation', does this mean that by default 'corporate' cannot be used as well?

Thanks,

Comment: Corporate as a noun is usually short for “[Corporate] Headquarters” which is a metonym for “The bigwigs who run the place”

Comment: @jim There *is* a noun form of [*corporate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corporate), but it means "a bond issued by a business corporation." In *corporate headquarters*, *corporate* is not a noun, it's an adjective. Similarly, that's the difference as it applies to the context of this question: *corporate* is an adjective and *corporation* is a noun.

Comment: According to Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries, corporate is also a noun. It is defined as 'a company, especially a large one'. @JasonBassford.

Comment: @Ohood.94 Wow, you're right. From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/corporate): 'Because of this amendment, corporates can now directly procure goods from farmers.’, ‘More and more corporates are therefore setting up centres in the city.’ And so on. Fascinating. I have never heard the word used this way before. I wonder if it's only done in UK English?

Comment: I would edit your question to provide links and dictionary definitions. Unless you can show a US English dictionary that has the same noun definition, it may be something regional.

Comment: I have checked Merriam Webster. You're right. Looks like corporate as a noun is only used in British English. @JasonBassford

Comment: A *corporate* is nothing but a "body corporate" which is a "corporation" or any other body that is "body corporate" under applicable law.

Comment: This question is better asked on a legal SE.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I was refereeing to the informal use of “Corporate” as in: “Did you read the new memo from Corporate this morning?”  or “You know wee can’t do that without permission from Corporate..”  Where as you say,  it derives from an adjective (Corporate Headquarters) but becomes a name which is clearly a noun, when used as I have shown here.

Comment: @Jim Ah. Even in US English, that makes sense. It's an interesting observation. But note that you've capitalized the word, which turns it into a proper noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford :-)

Comment: @Jim, would you consider reposting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @jsw29 -  It’s not clear to me that that is what OP was asking, because “Did you see the memo from Corporation this morning?” clearly doesn’t work.

Comment: I do a lot of editing for a business consultancy, and I occasionally see _corporates_ used in the sense of "large, established corporations." In fact, I edited a report just last week about collaborations between "startups" and "corporates." The usage is not particularly common in U.S. business English, but it has a following in Europe. And as [this Ngram graph for "corporates"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corporates&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorporates%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccorporates%3B%2Cc0) indicates, the usage is increasing.

Answer (score -1):

After editing in banking and academia for 25 years, I can attest to the fact that 'corporate' is sometimes used as a noun in business jargon, either meaning corporation, or often, as an abbreviation for 'corporate customer' in one large American bank. However, it always rubbed me (a linguistically conservative American) the wrong way.

Answer (score -1):

Corporate is a form of business. Basically, a corporate is a big company owned by shareholders. Corporation is a legal term. A corporation is the legal entity (a non-human legal person) that directly "owns" the corresponding corporate. Semantically, when one talks about business planning, cost and profits, company management, and other things related with running a big company, he should generally prefer the word "corporate". While strictly speaking, one can only strike a deal with a corporation (not a corporate), be employed by a corporation( not a corporate), or sue a corporation (not a corporate). But in informal language, the two words are often used interchangeably.